# Are there any simple types sizeof(which) > 1 is guaranteed?

Tags: c++, sizeof

When writing generic code, I often want a simple type `T` for which `sizeof(T) > 1` is guaranteed.

For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
char test_foo(...);
template <typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::foo)>>>
??? test_foo(int);
template <typename T>
struct has_foo : std::bool_constant<sizeof(test_foo<T>(0))!=1> {};
```

I have a few options, but none is ideal:

- `long long`: does not work, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types)
- `struct SizeNot1 { char dummy[2]; };`: have to define it ahead, a little bit annoying
- `char (&test_foo())[2];`: too ugly
- `std::array<char, 2>`: is its size guaranteed?

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you've mostly answered your own question. `long long` is good enough on any sane architecture, and if you need absolute guarantees from the standard, `char (&test_foo())[2]` will do. It can be `typedef`'d into something with a prettier name, and then you've got your solution. I'm pretty sure any [language-lawyer] solution is going to at least as ugly as that one.

Comment: Options 2-4 might as well all be `char[2]`, which presumably is to ugly for you.

Comment: `sizeof(uint16_t)` is guaranteed to be always be 2 (etc)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner ae you sure? because there is no guarantee that `char` has 8 bits.

Comment: Has C++ diverged from C by mandating that `CHAR_BIT` be 8?

Comment: @zwhconst why does `long long` not work according to you?

Comment: I believe `std::array<char,2>` should always have sizeof == 2

Comment: @RC0993 See the link. It says "Note: this allows the extreme case in which bytes are sized 64 bits, all types (including char) are 64 bits wide, and sizeof returns 1 for every type."

Comment: @Slava And that's another very puzzling issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/d9pzwe/guarantees_on_stdarray_inmemory_layout/

Comment: It would be nice to have `std::of_size_t<2>` ;-)

Comment: @zwhconst Even if the layout of `std::array<T, N>` differs from `T[N]`, size of `std::array<T, N>` can practically never be lesser than `T[N]`. As such, it is safe to assume that `sizeof std::array<T, N> >= sizeof T * N`, unless you want `sizeof std::array<T, 2>` to be exactly equals `2`.

Comment: Options #2, #3 and #4 should all work for the requirement.

Comment: All simple types of `short` or larger are guaranteed to have `sizeof(T) > 1` [5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) equivalent in C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `short`, `long` and `long long` can all be 1 byte. The only guarantee you have is `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes `short` and `int` contains at least 16 bits, `long` at least 32 bits and `long long` at least 64 bits. But who said that `char` contains 8 bits? If `CHAR_BIT == 64` then obviously all the types up to `long long` may be 1 byte. DSPs very usually have large `CHAR_BIT` because they don't often deal with octets. See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865505/are-there-any-simple-types-sizeofwhich-1-is-guaranteed?noredirect=1#comment119954194_67865505)

Comment: @phuclv Okay I'll admit defeat, I did the common mistake of equating one byte with one octet.

Comment: What about `std::bitset<CHAR_BIT + 1>`

Comment: @phuclv "*yes `short` and `int` contains at least 16 bits*" - likely, but not guaranteed. "*`long` at least 32 bits*" - likely, but also not guaranteed. And on some architectures, it is 64bit. "*and `long long` at least 64 bits*" - likely, but also not guaranteed. "*But who said that `char` contains 8 bits?*" - Noone, though that is the common size on most modern systems.

Comment: How about dropping `sizeof` and using `std::true_type`/`std::false_type` directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When writing generic code, I often want a simple type `T` for which `sizeof(T) > 1` is guaranteed.

I think you do it the "wrong" way.

For your example, you might directly use `std::true_type`/`std::false_type`.

```
template <typename>
std::false_type test_foo(...);

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::foo)>, int> = 0>
std::true_type test_foo(int);

template <typename T>
using has_foo = deltype(test_foo<T>(0));
```

If you need different compile_time number inside a type, [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) might help:

```
template <typename>
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> test_foo(...);

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::foo)>, int> = 0>
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 42> test_foo(int);

template <typename T>
using has_foo = std::bool_constant<deltype(test_foo<T>(0))() == 42>;
```

> `char (&test_foo())[2];`: too ugly

There are alternative syntaxes which are nicer:

```
auto test_foo() -> char(&)[2];
```

but using typedef would be even more readable IMO:

```
template <std::size_t N>
using c_char_array = char[N];
```

and then

```
c_char_array<2>& test_foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

It just comes to my head that this should work:

```cpp
std::aligned_storage_t<2> & test_foo(int);
```

This does not introduce new names and is fairly readable.

Comment: Actually, this [doesn't](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/18s8eG7nd) seem to work.

Comment: @cigien How does it not work? It outputs 16, which > 1.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure why I read the question as asking for exactly 2. So `decltype("42")` would work. I'm still not sure this solution is *guaranteed* to work, but that's a different question.

Comment: @cigien As said [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage#Member_types), `std::aligned_storage_t<Len>` is a POD type of at least size `Len`, so sizeof(it) >= 2. No?

Comment: Oh yes, that looks right. This is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sizeof(char) == 1`, you can use a `char[2]`. As you've mentioned, the syntax for that is

```
char (&test_foo())[2];
```

which works, but may be a bit difficult to read.

It's a subjective answer, but I think

```
decltype(" ") test_foo();
```

is fairly readable. Here we're just using the type of a literal of type `char[2]`.

Comment: `using char2 = char[2];` may make it a little less unpalatable.

Comment: @Eljay OP mentions that they don't want to have to declare a type beforehand, which I guess means avoiding a `using` alias as well.

Comment: Maybe this is better: `decltype("42") test_foo();` ;-)

Comment: @zwhconst I would have definitely used that if you wanted `sizeof` to be 3 :)

Comment: @cigien I wanted `sizeof(T) > 1`.

Comment: @zwhconst See Jarod42's answer. Not only does it show an even more convenient syntax as asked for, but also shows how you should approach the entire problem instead of what you're doing. It's a much better answer, and I think you should accept that one.

Comment: @cigien Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. If you trying to do template which detects presence of function, this how it can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    int func() {return 1;}
};

class B {
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_func : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_func<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().func())>>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
int wrap(T &t) {
    if constexpr (has_func<T>::value) {
        return t.func();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    std::cout << "A:" << wrap(a) << ", B:" << wrap(b) << "\n";
}
```